# Как добавить стили в header.php Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Добавил в header.php данный код.

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true) die();
IncludeTemplateLangFile(__FILE__);
?>

<?php use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php
        Asset::getInstance()->addString('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">');
        Asset::getInstance()->addString('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1">');
    ?>
    <title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?></title>
    <!--    Include CSS File    -->
    <?php
        Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/fonts/fonts.css");
        Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/css/style.css");
        Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/libs/owl.carousel.min.css");
        Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/libs/owl.theme.default.min.css");
        Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/libs/modal/style.css");
    ?>
</head>
```

Поместил все css/fonts в папку с шаблоном, но стили не подключаться.
В коде страницы вот такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset; 
    $APPLICATION->ShowHead(); // нужно было добавить
?>
```